# How can I prevent a third party from calling certain methods?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, encapsulation

I have an assembly which is being developed to create a facade around some potentially sensitive functionality and I want to allow a third party to call some of the methods contained within it but not others.

How can I prevent the third party calling unauthorised methods given they will have access to the entire DLL (I'm not concerned about them seeing the code, just executing it)?

This has to be compatible with the .net compact framework so unfortunately using the StrongNameIdentityPermission attribute is not possible.

Comment: Can you not just make the sensitive methods internal? (That doesn't prevent reflection, admittedly... but that's a different matter.)

Comment: I must be missing something here, do you want to prevent public members of the Facade API being invoked, or those of the underlying DLL?

Comment: The grand plan is to use the assembly in-house encapsulating all logic in one place – we will need to call the methods we don’t want the third party to call. The painful alternative is another assembly with a trimmed down subset of methods but that’s a daunting thought.

Comment: @Jon I was thinking the same thing, combined with obfuscation.

Comment: @MylesMcDonnell we want to be able to call the methods ourself but prevent the third party from doing so.

Comment: @AntSwift: Can you use InternalsVisibleTo within the assemblies of your own organization? (A trimmed down version which *delegates* to the full version would allow a more fine-grained approach, mind you. Then "LibraryForInternalUse" would grant access to internal methods to "LibraryForThirdPartyUse", the latter of which would delegate *some* methods publicly.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should ship two Facade implementations, one for 'internal' consumers which exposes all methods and another external that exposes only the sub-set.  You can achieve this whilst maintaining only one code base by having two separate build processes.  One technique that springs to mind is to use [compiler directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx) to exclude a method from the external build, or mark it internal if it is required by other public methods.  If you do ship sensitive methods with internal modifiers you may also want to implement obfuscation.

EDIT

Perhaps it would be cleaner, rather than having directives around each method to use partial classes, define a partial class for the sensitive methods and put the entire class implementation in a directive.

```
    public partial class MyClass
    {
        public void NonSensitive(){}
    }

    #if INTERNAL_BUILD
    public partial class MyClass
    {
        public void Sensitive(){}
    }
    #endif
```

You can have this partial class in the same or a separate file, which might be a nice level of separation as you could prepend the file name x_Sensitive.cs or similar.

Comment: This appeals as a clean solution. I'm looking for a way to integrate it into out build process.

Comment: Although kinda messy, this works great. We only need to build the limited version occasionaly so I'm happy just to manually set a conditional symbol for now.

Answer (score 2):

#### Description

Assuming i understand your question.

You can mark your methods with the `internal` access modifier to make them not
accessable from other librarys.

**But this does not help from security persepective, because it is always possible to run the method using reflection.**

> The internal keyword is an access modifier for types and type members. Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same assembly

#### More Information

- [MSDN - internal (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: From a security perspective this doesn't do anything to prevent these methods from being called unless restrictions are also placed on the use of reflection.

Comment: Yes i know, but i don't know if i understand the question at first. My answer is extended. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

If a third party can see the code, then they can run it - there is nothing you do to stop this.

Note however you have an application which is loading 3rd party plugins then you could load plugin assemblies with restrictions that prevent it from using reflection - this would mean that you can mark these methods / classes as `internal` to prevent plugins from being able to call these methods **when loaded as a plugin in your application**.  Depending on the nature of the sensitive functionality this may or may not be useful to you from a security perspective.

For information on how to do this see [How to: Run Partially Trusted Code in a Sandbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046.aspx)

Comment: This is not sctictly true, using the StrongNameIdentityPermissionAttribute, I could ensure that only code signed with our key could call the 'protected' code.

Comment: @Jusin "If a third party can see the code, then they can run it - there is nothing you do to stop this." If the third party tried to run the protected code, a SecurityException would be generated. http://www.morganskinner.com/Articles/StrongNameIdentityPermission/

Comment: @AntSwift My point is that if they can see the code then they can just reflect it, re-compile it into an assembly that is missing the given `StrongNameIdentityPermission` attribute and run that assembly instead - you need to take this into account for your application to be secure.

Comment: Following this up, my understanding is the re-compiled assembly will no longer be signed. The third-party would then need to sign the new assembly in order for my signed assembly to accept it. Is that correct?

Comment: @AntSwift Yes - generally speaking they would need to re-sign the assembly for your application to accept it. If you control the process you can control what runs inside that process.

Comment: In that case, using StrongNameIdentityPermission and signing both assemblies will mean that any attempt to reflect and re-compile excluding StrongNameIdentityPermission will mean the re-compiled assembly will not be executable (assuming the third party doesn’t have access to my key). Am I missing something?

Comment: It's worth noting that none of this is based on tests, just assumptions.

Comment: @AntSwift Unsigned assemblies are still *executable*. The only thing signing does is allow your application to test to ensure that the file has not been tampered with before loading & using it, however If the attacker just creates their **own** application that doesn't require that the assembly be signed then they can still run the code within that assembly.  Depending on what the code in that assembly is this may or may not be a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

Could you offer the functionality that you want the third party to consume as a Web API? They will not have any access to the source code OR the compiled binaries. They will only be able to see exactly what you want them to see. This would also offer additional security features such as Authentication and Authorization of callers.